Explanation of a Quantum Zeno Multiple Mach Zehnder Interferometer Arrangement
In this Interaction Free Measurement paper from 1995 [1], a series of connected Mach-Zehnder interferometers are shown in Figure 1. The paper says that principle is to ensure :"The reflectivity of each of the N beam splitters is chosen to be R = $cos^2 (\pi /2N)$, and the relative phases between the corresponding paths in the upper and lower halves to be zero. In figure 1(a) the result is that the amplitude of the photon undergoes a gradual transference from the lower to the upper halves of the interferometers. This coherent evolution of the light from one stage to the next is essential here. After all N stages the photon will then with certainty exit via the 'up' port of the final beam splitter"

My question is : What does the "coherent evolution of light from one stage to the next" mean / involve, e.g. what phase changes occur at the beam splitters / reflections and what formula applies at the exit of each Mach-Zehnder interferometer ? I ask since if the usual Mach-Zehnder properties are used, e.g. from the original paper [2], then the light would oscillate between the upper and lower paths due to symmetry considerations [i.e. with the paper's assumption of a $\pi /2$ phase shift per reflection no matter what direction the photon arrives at the beam splitter or mirror and the beam splitters have symmetric reflectivity to beams arriving from above & below.]
[1] https://research.physics.illinois.edu/QI/Photonics/papers/My%20Collection.Data/PDF/Interaction-Free%20Measurement.pdf
[2] https://www.tau.ac.il/~vaidman/lvhp/m28.pdf

This is not an easy paper to understand ... and it falls into the category of weak measurement (WM) in QM .... and the WM concept is by no means a verifiable effect, it is more in the thought realm.
Coherent evolution ... not clear but in general it would mean the photon(s) keep their own properties relative to themselves and each other as they photon(s) transfer from one stage to the next (phase and direction properties).  In any beam splitter (BS) there are phase changes at exit but for the purposes of this experiment (and any interferometer) the distances between interfaces (one BS to the next) takes into account the phase change so that all paths are equally probable.  In general in an MZ it is possible to tune either arm or both arms to a path length that is net 1/2 lambda offset and no transmission occurs.  When both paths have lengths an integer multiple of lambda transmission is 50/50 in the arms.
Be careful in this paper because they are always setting R to be biased off 50% thus influencing one path or the other.
In order to draw any conclusions in WM a large quantity of photons is required, the conclusion will always have a certain certainty.  If we only use 1 photon no conclusions can be made.
